# Cannot find /dev/sdX in grub, thus cannot exit

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, kernel

Recently, I was working on switching Ubuntu to Windows OS. I have forgotten what I have set in the `grub` GUI. When I rebooted my laptop, I found that I am stuck inside the `grub` command line. (see [grub command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS1mB.jpg)).

So, I followed a couple of guidelines from the websites, and all have stated to do the following:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt)
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdX
boot
```

However, as I was following these instructions, I was not able to find out that my SSD device (see [no device name like sdX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH1DI.jpg))

My laptop is an Acer Swift 3, 15 inches. Single boot OS (Ubuntu). I have tried checking the `/mnt` and I saw there's a folder called boot-save which contained my SSD name, but still, I can't point the `root` to it ( see [file under dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIB4U.jpg))

And everytime I just got a kernel panic error as shown.
How to solve it? 
I'm desperate and tired. Please help me.

Comment: This question may sound stupid, but did you try `linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sd0` or `linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sd1` instead of `.../sdX`. Sorry if that question may insult you.

Comment: Yes I have tried all. Still doesn't work. sdX the X is the number I have tried. From a1.... till I'm tired of trying.

Answer (score 1):

You are not loadin the `initrd`.

First check wich partition has the OS installed, the X a number of course thst also resembles the device `/dev/sdaX`.

With

```
ls (hd0,gptX)/
```

find the one with the linux folder's structure

```
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
initrd.img <== this file
initrd.img.old
lib
lib32
lib64
libx32
lost+found
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
vmlinuz
vmlinuz.old
```

As you can see there's a file called `initrd.img`.

So the command would be:

```
set root=(hd0,gptX)
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdX
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue on the same machine. Apart from having to load `initrd` as already pointed out, the discovered the path to my sdX in the following way:

1. put in an arbitrarily `sdX` into the `root=/dev/sdX`
2. load `initrd` and then run `boot`
3. got an error in the BusyBox (initramfs) shell, saying the `root` path is wrong
4. once in the shell, I ran `ls /dev/` and could see all the sdXs, unlike before in grub, mine ended up being `sda2`